# JavaScript and CSS: display a div over an element on mouseover

Tags: javascript, css

I want to display a div over an element (especially a link) when hovered, like in Facebook, when you hover a profile picture.

I know this could be done with JavaScript and CSS but have no exact idea.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use jQuery?

Comment: Well, I don't have idea about jQuery. Never gone through it. I hope it is not the only option.

Comment: $jQuery.show() would be your best option.  Never be afraid to try something new (unless it's on production).

Comment: Its not that I'm afraid. But I have a limited time right now, and can't go throught the tutorials of jQuery.

Comment: Using jQuery for this task is like using a power washer to clean your dishes. It's a great, useful tool -- but not intended to be used for jobs like this (unless you're already using it for something else, I suppose... but I'd still argue CSS is the way to go).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook's approach is to simply use CSS, which won't work in all browsers. In those browsers Facebook ditches the effect and always shows the element that should only display on hover:

```
#parent #child {
  display: none;
}
#parent:hover #child {
  display: block;
}
```

Use conditional CSS to set `display: block` as the default in IE7 and below.

Answer (score 1):

This can actually be done with pure css, here is a simple example:

HTML:

```
<div id='outer'>
    <div id='button'>
        <!-- your element here -->
    </div>
    <div id='popup'>
        <!-- your popup menu here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#popup {
    visibility:hidden;
}

#outer:hover #popup {
    visibility:visible;
}
```